# How to give Trigger generated value into Hibernate ValueObject?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

In my Hibernate Application i'm using create a ValueObject class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserVO{

    @Id
    @Column(name="S_ID")
    private String s_id;

    @Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="LASTNAME")
    private String lastName;
 }
```

and in my Service class i'm writing like this

```
public void createOrUpdateUser(UserVO userVO) {
        userDAO.createOrUpdateUser(userVO);
    }
```

and in my DAO class i'm writing like this

```
private EntityManager entityManager;
public void createOrUpdateUser(UserVO userVO) throws DataAccessException {
        entityManager.persist(userVO);
    }
```

now i'm calling createOrUpdateUser(userVO) but it give error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()
```

Actually my data base i have created one `trigger` for `user` table to generate unique id for `s_id` column is their any problem for trigger..please suggest me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ID column must not be null, whatever you do in database driver, will only be trigger before/after insert or any other operation, But according to error it is giving error before any error.

Set something to ID values or try something
 `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a trigger, the intended generation strategy is `org.hibernate.id.SelectGenerator`.  However, in order to use this strategy, Hibernate must be able to locate the inserted row after insertion to see what value the trigger assigned there are 2 ways to do this.

First is to specifically configure the generator to tell it a column that define a unique key (at least logically) within the table:

```
@Id
@Column(name="S_ID")
@GeneratedValue( strategy = "trigger" )
@GenericGenerator( 
    name="trigger", strategy="org.hibernate.id.SelectGenerator",
    parameters = {
        @Parameter( name="keys", value="userName" )
    }
)
private String s_id;

private String userName;
```

The other is via Hibernate's natural-id support:

```
@Id
@Column(name="S_ID")
@GeneratedValue( strategy = "trigger" )
@GenericGenerator( name="trigger", strategy="org.hibernate.id.SelectGenerator" ) )
private String s_id;

@NaturalId
private String userName;
```

GenerationType.IDENTITY may work for you.  It will really come down to the JDBC driver and how (if) it implements `getGeneratedKeys`

Comment: `@GeneratedValue( strategy = "trigger" )` gives a compilation error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to GenerationType` How to resolve this?

Comment: there's an error in @GeneratedValue. Correct is: @GeneratedValue( strategy = "trigger" ) Also instead of: @Parameter( name="keys", value="userName" ) should be: @Parameter( name="key", value="userName" )

Answer (score 0):

as @vinit said :

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
@Column(name="S_ID")
private String s_id;
```

is the best choice ...