# Hibernate populate primary key using database trigger

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, oracle10g, jpa-2.0

I am using Hibernate 4.1.0.Final with Spring 3

I have the following in Entity class

```
@Id
@Column(name = "PROJECT_NO")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
private String projectNumber;
```

Is it possible to use database trigger to populate the primary key of a table? Or I have to use a CustomGenerator for this?

When I tried the above I have the following exception

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: Unknown integral data type
for ids : java.lang.String
```

Database trigger doesn't have any sequence, it is using

```
SELECT NVL (MAX (project_no), 0) + 1 FROM projects
```

Edit 1

```
@GeneratedValue(generator="trig")
@GenericGenerator(name="trig", strategy="select", 
parameters=@Parameter(name="key", value="projectNo"))
```

The above throws the following exception

```
Hibernate: select PROJECT_NO from PROJECTS where PROJECT_NO =?

java.lang.NullPointerException
exception in save null
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:645)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getPropertyValue(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4268)
    at org.hibernate.id.SelectGenerator$SelectGeneratorDelegate.bindParameters(SelectGenerator.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.performInsert(AbstractSelectingDelegate.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2764)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3275)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a String instead of a numeric value. Use a Long instead of a String, and your error will disappear.

AFAIK, you can't use a trigger to populate the ID. Indeed, Hibernate would have to retrieve the generated ID, but since it doesn't have an ID, I don't see how it could read back the row it has just inserted (chicken and egg problem).

You could use your SQL query to get an ID before inserting the row, but this strategy is inefficient, and has a risk of duplicate IDs in case of concurrent inserts. So I wouldn't use this strategy. You tagged your post with Oracle. I suggest you use a sequence. that's what they're for.

Comment: I agree with you that sequence is the way to go, however database guys for this applications is insisting on having a trigger.

Comment: What if I am using a CustomGenerator to get value from database instead of sql query? Is this inefficient or both are one and same?

Answer (score 2):

As of this on the [Hibernate 3.3 documentation page](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id) you can do that.

> **select**
>
> retrieves a primary key, assigned by a database trigger, by selecting
>   the row by some unique key and retrieving the primary key value.

Comment: @Polppan as of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085508/how-to-give-trigger-generated-value-into-hibernate-valueobject . You can use @GeneratedValue( strategy = "trigger" ) and then have a NaturalID in your Entity

Comment: Garis, `@GeneratedValue( strategy = "trigger" )` is complaining about `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to GenerationType`. Any idea about this?

Comment: Usage of `GenerationType.Auto` causes the following `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist`

Comment: Garis, I have added an update in my original question as Edit 1, At runtime I am getting null pointer exception, even though trigger exists in table.